# tar with -T - and prevent creating empty archive

Tags: tar, archiving

I must use tar with -T - and get backed up file list from stdin.
Untoftunately when input list is empty, tar creates empty archive. I want prevention to this.

It is possible induce tar to do "Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive" instead creating empty archive with -T - option?

I know, I can examine archive is empty by simply call

```
tar tvF|head -n 1|grep -c ^       #we are interested in only first file exists or not
```

then decide remove empty or not.

But I want more elegant solution